# What is the JDBC package name for MsSql db inside Class.forName("")?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

For H2 db its

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
```

For MySql db its

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver")
```

What is it for MsSql?

Comment: You don't need that with any modern (>= Java 6) JDBC driver

Comment: Your question is answered in the [driver's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#making-a-simple-connection-to-a-database)

Comment: And for MySQL it is actually `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` (capital D) or `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` (when using version 8 of the driver).

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#making-a-simple-connection-to-a-database), it's

> ```
> Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
> ```

However, in almost all normal usages of JDBC, you don't need this since 2006 (Java 6), with the introduction of automatic driver loading. There are some exceptions where you still need to load explicitly, but in situations where that is necessary, there are usually better ways of obtaining a JDBC connection (ie through a configured `javax.sql.DataSource`).

<sup>NOTE: This answer builds on the comments by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name).</sup>